Vacuum cleaner design
Is there a good reason for designing a vacuum cleaner to cool itself using the air that it's just sucked up?
I've been helping a friend with a lot of very-dusty DIY recently, and we've managed to damage 3 vacuum cleaners in as many weeks. I've just finished the autopsy for each and they've all got the same design flaw and same cause of death.
Each vacuum sucks in air and debris, filters the debris out using a cyclone or filter or bag, then passes the same air through the motor to provide cooling. This works fine if the filtration process is good. If the air still contains debris then it can (and does) clog up bearings and commutators - this seems to what's killed all three of them. They're all a bit bashed and battered, but I think one's a Henry, one's a vac-master, the last a dyson.
Is there a good engineering reason for building like this? They're all different brands, so it's obviously standard practice. The only reasons I can think of is that this design might be easier and cheaper to build? or is there something else?

Have you tried cleaning them out more often?  Maybe get a 4th vacuum cleaner that has a "bag dirty" indicator and paying attention to it?

The engineering need is to produce a device at a price people will buy, with maximum performance.
You could theoretically make a motor that runs cooler and doens't need so much cooling.  This will be a larger more costly device.
You could also have a separate path for cooling air.  This will take power you could have used for suction to use it to push cleaner air through the motor, plus the space for this extra fan and air flow.  So again, more cost, less performance.
I suggest that your specific problem is that the filtration is insufficient for your needs.  Considering that there are vacuums rated for vacuuming up radioactive contamination, I'm sure that filtration exists that will give you what you need, although these specialty devices will come at a premium price.

The failure of the devices thus far is an indication of a use case outside of design parameters. In plain english, they weren't made to do the job for which you are using them.
There is an alternative that can be used with any vacuum unit, ensuring clean air for cooling. Various names are used but vortex is almost always in the name. Vortex vacuum accessory, vortex vacuum separator, etc. Sometimes, one sees cyclone as part of the terminology.
I purchased a Cyclone™ brand unit, but it seems to have vanished from the internet and has been replaced by many other manufacturers. Some manufacturers integrate such a device into the vacuum cleaner, while the less-expensive option is to buy an add-on unit, such as I did.
The unit is placed between the pickup wand and the vacuum source. The incoming air with debris is forced into a decreasing diameter spiral, which eventually causes the debris to drop to the bottom, while the lower-mass airflow is directed upward to the vacuum source/cleaner.
I demonstrated this unit to a friend who runs a powdercoating shop. Powder coat powder is considered a health risk as the particulate size is small enough to slip through many filters, including standard vacuum cleaner filters. This causes the vacuum cleaner to eject the particles into the air.
Using the cyclone cleaner on a test pile of powdercoat powder resulted in zero ejecta, a completely empty vacuum cleaner bin and all of the powder contained within the cyclone unit.
The outgoing air in such a system is going to have full cooling capability when it reaches the vacuum cleaner motor.

Worked brilliantly for me, but then the motor burned out from insufficient airflow -- the vortex unit caused too much pressure drop.

That's a curious development. Some parameter mismatch was the problem? Too small for the tubing or the opening to the vortex or at the exit?

There will be a pressure drop, and a reduction of flow, at a vortex unit. The better it is, the bigger the effect. A pass-through design which depends on air flow for cooling is susceptible to failure if the there is insufficient airflow.

I don't know what is standard for wet-and-dry vacuums, but you can certainly buy industrial-grade cleaners with separate air paths.
https://vacuumdoctor.com.au/products/nilfisk-ca-410-electric-scrubber-240v-vacuum-motor-kit

thanks @david, but how can you tell is has separate air paths? is it the phrase '2 stage' ?
